# Javascript Duplicate a div in html and get the values from duplicated div's in form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

In my codeigniter view, I've a div containing a select box and a textbox. Also there is an 'Add more' button. My task is to duplicate this whole div when the add more button is clicked and when I submit the form I need to get the field values from the original div and duplicated div's. How Can I accomplish this? I tried duplicating div using **jquery clone method**. But couldn't find the solution.

Here is the code what I tried so far:

```
    <?php echo form_open("vehicle/addparts");?>
    <div class="row" id="addparts">
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control input-medium" name="parts">
    <option value="">select disabled>Select Parts</option>
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b">B</option>
    <option value="c">C</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Quantity</label>
    <input type="text" name="partsquantity" id="partsquantity">
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <input type="button" name="addmore" value="Add More" onClick="duplicate">
    </div>
    <?php echo form_close();?>
Javascript:

    <script>
    function duplicate() {    
    var original = document.getElementById('addparts');
    var clone = original.cloneNode(true);
    clone.id = "duplic";
    document.bodey.append(clone);
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: one thing i noticed is typo in your code. `document.bodey.append(clone);` this should be `document.body.append(clone);` if you are appending code in body. But your code should not work as you expect.

Comment: Hi , how to add a button remove  ? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<?php echo form_open("vehicle/addparts");?>

        <div class="row" id="addparts">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select class="form-control input-medium" name="parts[]">
                        <option value="">select disabled>Select Parts</option>
                        <option value="a">A</option>
                        <option value="b">B</option>
                        <option value="c">C</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Quantity</label>
                    <input type="text" name="partsquantity[]" id="partsquantity">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" id="div_button">
            <input type="button" name="addmore" value="Add More" id="addMore">
        </div>
          <?php echo form_close();?>

rename the of the inputs to be array so that if you submit the form it will submit all the input elements
you will receive a array of values with particular naming groupings
```

javascript

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        var id = 1;

        // get item

        var item = $("#addparts");

        var before = $('#div_button');

        // initalize event click

       $('#addMore').on('click', function() {
            // clone addparts
            var clone = item.clone(true);
                // remove id
                clone.attr('id', '');
                // add class duplicate
                clone.attr('class', 'duplicate');
            // insert duplicate before button div
            before.before(clone);


       });

    });


</script>
enter code here
```

Comment: Hi , how can I add a button remove  ? Thanks

Comment: @SinsilMathew can we create dynamic id or name here?

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem is that you are cloning the div and appending the div inside the body.
This means your form doesn't contain your cloned divs.
If you can use jquery try following code

```
var clonedDiv = $('#addparts').clone();
function duplicate() {   
  $("#addparts").after(clonedDiv );
}
```

And now try to submit the form.

Comment: I think name of DOM `element` should be overwrite when `clone` the div. Then how can retrieve each DOM value?

Comment: @Sadikhasan clone method doesn't override any thing in original element. please check http://api.jquery.com/clone/
But still after your suggestion I can optimize my code  little more.

Comment: I mean when you clone with DOM `element` then it also `cloned` and when you submit form then which `DOM element` value post? How can you differentiate? My suggestion is use name like array `parts[]`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with codeigniter. But i am providing the simple jquery code to add the clone of existing form div.

I modified the two lines:

```
<div class="row button-div">
<input type="button" name="addmore" class="addmore" value="Add More">
```

then use the following jquery code.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.addmore').click(function(e){
      $clone = $('#addparts').clone();
      $clone.attr('id', 'row-' + ($('.row').length + 1) );
      $clone.insertBefore($('.button-div'));  
      });
    });
```

**Note:** Not forget to include jquery on page.

check jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/msankhala/ybqzwx9n/

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id='addparts' class='clone'>
    <div class="row" id="copy">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <select class="form-control input-medium" name="parts[]">
                    <option value="">select disabled>SelectParts</option>
                    <option value="a">A</option>
                    <option value="b">B</option>
                    <option value="c">C</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Quantity</label>
                <input type="text" name="partsquantity[]" id="partsquantity">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="div_button">
        <input type="button" name="addmore" value="Add More" id="addMore">
    </div></div>
```

JavaScript:`$("#addMore").click(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var cloned = $("#copy:first").clone(true)
                    .appendTo('#addparts');
                   });`